# g tag rect shape to moldable shape and text inside g tag to wrap and be responsive in angular7

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, svg

My Objective is:

1) Instead of rect tag my aim is to make the rect object remoldable(as in it can be changed to any polygon when the vertices of the rect shape is clicked twice the side should be added by 1 , so by default it is 4 side , when the user clicks on a vertex then 1 more edge should be added , so it will become pentagon-5sides)

2) The text inside the g tag shape should wrap and be responsive it hsould become bigger wrt to the gtag when g tag becomes bigger and viceversa

ts code

```
drop(event:any){
event.preventDefault();
let data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text"),
 x = (event.clientX - event.srcElement.parentElement.offsetLeft - 80),
 y = (event.clientY - event.srcElement.parentElement.offsetTop),
 inner = `<g>
 <rect
  class = "draggable"
  fill = "#e24301"
  fill-opacity = "0.2"
  stroke = "#24301"
  stroke-width = "1.5"
  style = "pointer-events:inherit"
  x= inherit
  y= inherit
  width='${this.zoneAttribute.minWidth}'
  height='${this.zoneAttribute.minHeight}'
  id='${data}
  stroke-dasharray="none"
  onContextMenu="return false;">
  </rect>
  <text
   x= inherit
   y= inherit
   style='user-select: none'>
   ${data}
   </text>
   <text
   style='cursor:pointer; user-select: none'
   class="close"
   x= inherit
   y= inherit
   >X
   </text>
   <text
   style='user-select: none'
   class="temp-display"
   x= inherit
   y= inherit
   >
   </text>
   </g>`,
   close = document.getElementByClassName('close');

   (<HTMLDivElement>event.target.parentElement.querySelector
   ('.from-them')).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',inner);
   for(let i=0; i<close.length; i++){
    close[i].addEventListner('click',(event: Event) => {});
   }
   if(event.target.getElementById(data)){
        this.changeDimension(event.currentTarget.lastElementChild);
   }
   (<HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById(''+ (data) + '').style.display = 'none';
   }

   changeDimension(event:any){
    interact(event.firstElementChild)
        .draggable({
          inertia: true,
          restrict: {
           restriction: '.from-them',
           endonly: true,
           elementRect: {top:0, left:0, bottom:1, right:1}
          },
          autoscroll: true,
          onmove: this.dragMoveListner,
          onend: function(event){
           const textEl = event.target.querySelector('.close');

           textEl && (textEl.textContent =
            'moved a distance of'
            +(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.pageX - event.x0, 2)+
             Math.pow(event.pageY - event.y0, 2) | 0))
             .toFixed(2) + 'px');

          }
        })
        .ressizable({
            edges: {left: true, right:true, bottom:true, top:true}
        })
        .on('resizemove',(event:any) =>{
            let target = event.target,
             x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
             y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0)

             target.style.width = event.rect.width < this.zoneAttribute.minWidth ? this.zoneAttribute.minWidth :
             event.rect.width + 'px';
             target.style.width = event.rect.width < this.zoneAttribute.minHeight ? this.zoneAttribute.minHeight :
             event.rect.height + 'px';

             x += event.deltaRect.left;
             y += event.deltaRect.top;

             target.style.webKitTransform = target.style.transform = 'translate('+ x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
             target.nextElementSibling.style.transform = 'translate('+ x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
             target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.transform = 'translate('+ x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
             target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.transform = 'translate('+ x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
             target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
             target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
        });
   }

   dragMoveListner(event:any){

    const target = event.target,
     x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
     y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

      target.style.webKitTransform = target.style.transform = 'translate('+ x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
      target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
      target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
      target.nextElementSibling.style.transform = 'translate('+ x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
      target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.transform = 'translate('+ x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
      target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.transform = 'translate('+ x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';


   }
```

html code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="imgpos" viewBox="0 0 80 80" 
class="form-them" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" (drop)="drop($event)"
[innerHTML]= "abcsvg | safeHtml" [ngStyle]="{'background- 
image':'url('+url+')', 'background-repeat':'no-repeat', 'background- 
position':'center','background-size':'contain'}">

  __________________________________
 |    _______   ______              |
 |   |       | |      |--> g tag    |----> svg image
 |   |_______| |______|             |
 |__________________________________|
```

For ref the snippet from the above ts code which is for the g tag

```
  inner = `<g>
 <rect
  class = "draggable"
  fill = "#e24301"
  fill-opacity = "0.2"
  stroke = "#24301"
  stroke-width = "1.5"
  style = "pointer-events:inherit"
  x='${x}'
  y='${y}'
  width='${this.zoneAttribute.minWidth}'
  height='${this.zoneAttribute.minHeight}'
  id='${data}
  stroke-dasharray="none"
  onContextMenu="return false;">
  </rect>
  <text
   x='${x+40}'
   y='${y+40}'
   style='user-select: none'>
   ${data}
   </text>
   <text
   style='cursor:pointer; user-select: none'
   class="close"
   x='${x+80}'
   y='${y+20}'
   >X
   </text>
   <text
   style='user-select: none'
   class="temp-display"
   x='${x+40}'
   y='${y+25}'
   >
   </text>
   </g>`
```

Comment: So the update is changing the style in dom of rect element directly, the value of x :inherit, y:inherit, in rect tag brings the g tag structure inside my svg image ,but doing it in my ts code is not reflecting the same, so any help would be great.

Comment: I guess its responsive as well but not able to make it working from ts code , I had changed the attributes in chrome dev tools and checked it is working, I changed x:inherit, y:inherit, but on dragging the g tag image it goes out of the svg image and kind of disappears (might be due to transform) , please suggest.

Comment: Any help @Günter Zöchbauer , thanks